# Run motion commands on VIM startup

Tags: vim

When I start vim, I want to automatically have a few buffers open. So far I have this

```
au VimEnter * :split | :vsplit | :vsplit
```

Now I want to do a `Ctrl-w` followed by a `j` and then call `:vsplit` 2 more times so that my editor window looks like a grid of 6 buffers.

How can I run a basic motion command automatically (e.g. moving down a window)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:wincmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Awincmd)

```
au VimEnter * :split | :vsplit | :vsplit | :wincmd j | :vsplit | :vsplit
```

Answer (score -1):

`nmap <c-w>j :vsplit<CR>`

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: sorry, I'm quite new here .. my bad.